# problem with foreign key in populating database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
Deleting previous tuples from flights
 Error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationExcepti
on: Duplicate entry 'AAH196' for key 'PRIMARY'
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Dupl
icate entry 'AAH196' for key 'PRIMARY'

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1041)

        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3498)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2562)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1664)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1583)
        at Populate.Populate_flights(Populate.java:94)
        at Populate.<init>(Populate.java:36)
        at Populate.main(Populate.java:28)

Deleting previous tuples from reservationsInserting Data into table building Err
or 2: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException
: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cs585hw3`.`
reservations`, CONSTRAINT `reservations_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`flight_no`) REFERE
NCES `flights` (`flight_no`))
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cann
ot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cs585hw3`.`reserv
ations`, CONSTRAINT `reservations_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`flight_no`) REFERENCES `
flights` (`flight_no`))

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1041)

        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3498)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2562)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1664)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1583)
        at Populate.Populate_reservations(Populate.java:126)
        at Populate.<init>(Populate.java:37)
        at Populate.main(Populate.java:28)
```

I have two tables. flights.data and reservations.data. I am trying to populate the tables via jdbc. While populating it, I am getting the above error.

There is a foreign key reference from reservations to flights.I have to delete records from the secondary table first. This would mean, I should delete records from reservations before I delete from flights. Is that Correct? I checked my table, reservations table has a foreign key. SO I have to delete the data first from this table.

But How do I perform this task?

In the reservation function, I doing like this,

```
Statement s = conn.createStatement();

        s.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM reservations");
```

In the table function, it is same like this , instead , I used delete from table.Please tell how would I fix it.

Comment: why there is no one to answer it???

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the primary key of the row you're trying to delete in flights?  Let's say it is 5.

```
long flightId = 5;
Statement s = c.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM reservations WHERE flight_id = ?");
s.setLong(1,flightId);
s.executeUpdate();
```

At that point, you can delete your flight because there will be no reservations pointing back to it.

```
s.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM flights WHERE id = ?");
s.setLong(1, flightId);
s.executeUpdate();
```

EDIT: if you want to remove all date from both tables:

```
Statement s = c.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM reservations");
s.executeUpdate();

s = c.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM flights");
s.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: no, actually my table has 1 entry that is pointing to one of the entries in flight table. So whenever, I populate the database, I have to remove the old entries in the table and then populate it. so that there will be no redundant data.I can't use the above method.I just need to make something in the program that deletes the entries from reservation table first and then flight table.

Comment: Oh, ok. In that case, yes, you should be able to use the mysql TRUNCATE sql statement. First, "TRUNCATE reservations" and then, "TRUNCATE flights".

Comment: but I am using two different functions,one for flight and other for reservations. In the flight, I am inserting my data from a data file placed on my desktop. If i dont use the delele statment in that function of flight, it will add redundant data in it. And then after executing the next fnction, data will be removed from the flight table.

Comment: would it work?? You want me to use this code in my reservation table but what about flight??

Comment: I'm sorry shilps, maybe someone else can help out. I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: Sir,I am using like :  public void Populate_flights() - in this function , what I should use to remove all the entries of flight table. The entries of flight table are present in reservation table. They are not letting me to do it.